# Summing groups of rows together? DAX formula using PowerPivot?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, business-intelligence, powerpivot, dax

I am trying to sum up multiple rows in a PowerPivot model but have them grouped:

For instance if there are 20 total rows, Project A, B, C, D, E, F (5 projects - 4 entries per each project.

Is it possible to add up but group them? So for instance:
If:
Project 1 5 hours
Project 1 5 hours
Project 1 6 Hours
Project 1 3 hours
Project 1 5 hours
Project 2 5 hours
Project 2 5 hours
etc.

Is it possible to use DAX (Maybe Summarize?) to add them up but group it so the result would return as:
Project 1 = 24 hours (which is all of them added up 5+5+6+3+5) and
Project 2 = 10 hours (which is both project 2's added up, 5+5)

and so on and so forth?

I was looking at the =SUMMARIZE and followed the syntax but it would always give me an error/not work how I wanted it to.

Comment: robromo, could you please share some sample data?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a calculation within the model as an intermediate step in a calculation? Or do you just need to show the sum in a report so you need this in the query/presentation layer?

Comment: What is the structure of your data? Assuming it is (ProjectName,Hours,...) you do not need to do anything. Just create a Measure with formula "Sum([Hours])" (Quotes for clarity). Once you create this measure then add ProjectName to Row and this newly created measure to values.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please clarify why you need to do this via a DAX calculation? If you added a simple =SUM() calculation and then added Project to your PivotTable, then the context of each of those calculations would automatically result in the answers that you're looking for. Here's an example:

**Sample Table**

- Table Columns

  - Project
  - Hours

**SAMPLE DATA IN TABLE**

```
Project 1,5
Project 1,5
Project 1,6
Project 2,5
Project 2,5
Project 1,3
Project 1,5
```

**Calculated Field**:
`TotalHours:=Sum([Hours])`

**PivotTable**:

Values: TotalHours
Rows: Project (You could also choose a specific project as a filter)

**Results**:

```
Project 1: 24
Project 2: 10
```

In this example, because the context of each cell in which the TotalHours calculated field is used is limited to a single Project, you don't need to do anything special to group them to get the results you're hoping for.

Of course - this is all a moot point if you're trying to use these calculations as an intermediate step...